# Slackを介して二つのコンピュータ間でデータのやり取りをするのは可能でしょうか

Tags: slack

LAN環境ではファイルのやり取りなどをするのはftpアプリケーションを用いるあるいは大抵の場合OS標準の「共有」の機能を用いれば容易に実現が可能なのですが

WANですと何かと面倒です。
実現自体は可能ですが、あまり詳しくない人たちにもそれをやらせようとすると、大抵の場合面倒くさがって結局メールなどに頼ることになってしまいます。

そこでSlackのようなインタラクティブなAPIも備えるツールを使ってできるかもしれないと思ったのですが、どうなのでしょうか。

私自身、全くと言っていいほど技術面の知識がありませんが、努力して質問したいことを書き連ねました。何卒よろしくお願いします。

Comment: 「Slackを介してネットワーク上のサーバーにsftp接続を行い」がどういうことなのかよくわりません、そもそもの目的はなんなのでしょうか。また、どうしてsftpなのでしょうか？「sftpプロトコル作成」とある辺り何かを勘違いされてる可能性もあるかと思う節があるのも合わせて。

Comment: ご指摘ありがとうございます、確かに自分の目指す具体例を示していませんでしたし、ファイル転送周りにもそこまで詳しくない身ですので、質問内容を吟味して編集あるいは再投稿いたします。

Comment: もう少し宣伝的な紹介から。[ファイルの共同編集やドキュメントの共有も Slack で](https://slack.com/intl/ja-jp/document-sharing)

Answer (score 1):

公式のドキュメントにファイルを共有する方法が記載されています。

[ファイルを Slack に追加する](https://slack.com/intl/ja-jp/help/articles/201330736)